# interpolating colors between random relived pixels of damaged image

Tags: c++, image, bitmap, 2d, interpolation

assume i got some bitmap image like 2000x2000 (it is 4M) pixels but the iumage is very heavily damaged so i only got few thousands random pixels 'relived' and rest is lost (say filled with black or transparency color) I would like to restore the image from those few pixels just by interpolation to get something that would resemble the oryginal image (but assume the pixels that relived are rare (less than 1% of oryginal) and randomly distrubuted, by randomly i mean like noise, both relived pixels are distrubuted like noise and deleted like noise, though as i said the relived amount is like 1% or less )

How to exactly interpolate among the 'relived' pixels... I mean what code function to use? or how such alghoritm to feeling up 'bleck' lost space should be used? much tnx for exact good answer

Comment: for each pixel you want, find the nearest `n` pixels available. Then do a weighted average with the weight being `1/distance` for each pixel.

Comment: Or do a sparse 2d fourrier transform and invert it to get something back, might be interesting

Comment: how many pixels? as i understand the relived would make something like mosaic of triangles  so maybe i should use something based on that fact? i couldnt interpolate based on more distant pisel as as you know images sjould be rather interpolated locally not from distant colors which gas nothing to do with it..so this answer you say is not much exact to me

Comment: also 'find the nearest n is not quite proper probably as image the pixel i want to colorize has 3 nearest points relived that are all below it (on screen ) and to retrieve color i rather should use something inbetween the below relived pixel and the above relived pixel, same as takin something from left and right (not just n nearest)- but i dont know more exactly what

Comment: If you're concerned about distant pixels skewing the interpolation, then use a non-linear weight. For example the square of the inverse distance. Or more generally, the inverse distance raised to some power greater than 1.0. You're not going to receive an "exact answer" to your question. You should try various approaches. You might even want to experiment with filling-in missing data via layers of mip-mapping. Or running a Dilate algorithm over your data and running post-processing. Or use Intel's Open Image Denoiser. Or use machine learning techniques... _etc_

Comment: im not sure if what yu say is right imagine for exampel i got only 15 points of color - it seem to me that if  you will draw apropriate lines it would be mosaic of triangles that coer the area in more proper way, i mean i could interpolate that triangle colors then - and this seen to me much more proper than taking various near points regardles if those are that three ...but dont know how to do it... i guess its not so hard i only need someone who knows how to do it..this inverse distance im syre would be heavily errorous

Comment: I don't think you're understanding correctly. You complained that linear interpolation has too much influence from a distant point. So I suggested altering the weighting function for averaging points based on distance. With a non-linear weight, as points become more distant their influence drops away faster. You'll still have an issue at the corners where you need to invent data. I'm even more convinced now that nobody here can satisfy you. You should spend more time actually trying techniques, rather than theorizing. Plenty of approaches suggested already. Who knows where they might lead.

Comment: you know that when you got pisture the point you dont get is not dependant on further pixels only to the closest ones..do you realize that? se for example image in my avatar dog nose is black and i shouldnt use color of hand to restore dogs nose - same is with distance - interpolation is "among" upa nd downa and left and right not just to NEAR pixels...so those what say take just near are for sure wrong///i understand you dont know the answer so..well..maybe someone else will know...i may wait one day

Comment: on fact i may use those N nearest apprach as its easy and will give something..but i dont think its much good and searching for something clearer... the nearest approach is not good just becouse this specific of images asume 1d case you got say some blue pixel on the left and some freen on the right - so you should set something among green and blue, if there is red after green on right it jas literally nothing to that greenblue point so for me its rather clear i should only take some surrounding points for consideration not just nearest